# Pulsar enter haga una acción

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo este html :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <textarea class="w100" ng-model="comment" name="comment">  
    </textarea>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="button" ng-click="saveChat(comment)" value="Send"/>
</div>
```

Cuando estoy escribiendo en el textarea si le doy a enter da un salto de linea, como hago para que haga click en el boton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacer un evento `onkeypress` y si esa tecla pulsada es un <kbd>Intro</kbd>([`keyCode 13`](http://keycode.info/)) que pulse el botón.

Puse que además no esté pulsada el <kbd>Shift</kbd> para que si lo mantienes pulsado si puedas saltar la linea

```js
function pulsar(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var boton = document.getElementById("boton");
            angular.element(boton).triggerHandler('click');
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="w100" ng-model="comment" name="comment" onkeypress="pulsar(event)">  

    <input type="button" ng-click="saveChat(comment)" value="Send" id="boton" />
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, funciona!

Comment: me alegra ser de ayuda, @sirdaiz. Un saludo

Comment: Buenas. Una duda de la respuesta. En el caso de no utilizar angular, como despliego el evento "click"? con $('#id').on('click')?

Answer (score 0):

mira puedes utilizar el listener "OnKeyPress" y la funcion verificando la propiedad .code

```js
function Enter(e) {
    if (e.code === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
        let i=document.getElementById("input").value="";
        console.log("buscar: "+i)
     
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Search" onKeyPress="Enter()">
```